# Programmatically instantiating a Delegate to a component

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch

I have an app which has a controller which already handles UITextFieldDelegate for textfields, now I want to add a second controller + UITextField programmatically which is separately from the main controller but is called from it.

So I have a MainController which handles input (that is working), then next to that, I defined this:

```
@interface TestUIDelegate : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>{
```

TestUIDelegate has a property textField.

TestUIDelegate has a method:

```
- (void)initGUI:(UIView *)myView;
```

which initialises a textField like thus:

```
- (void)initGUI:(UIView *)myView {
    self.view = myView;
    textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 200, 300, 40)];
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    textField.placeholder = @"enter text";
    textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;

    textField.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:textField];
}
```

which also works; the field shows up and is editable, keyboard comes up and you can type stuff.

So far so good, but now I want to Done button to work so the keyboard is dismissed, so I added:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    NSLog(@"Here?");

   return YES;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

   NSLog(@"Or here?");
}
```

To my TestUIDelegate (actually I added all delegate methods from TextUIFieldDelegate).

I instantiate the TestUIDelegate from the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in the MainController like this:

```
TestUIDelegate *controller = [[TestUIDelegate alloc] init];
[controller initGUI:self.view];
```

TextField still shows up the delegate methods are never called, none of them. Now I imagine i'm doing something very weird and I have looked through all answers on SO and in Google slightly relating to this, but they all do it by implementing the delegates in the MainController which is exactly what I really do not want. And I need it programmatically; not (at all) with the gui builder.

Can anyone enlighten me please? I don't think i'm going to figure this out on my own.

Comment: How are you calling this controller and calling the method initGUI?

Comment: Like this TestUIDelegate *controller = [[TestUIDelegate alloc] init];
[controller initGUI:self.view];  from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions of the MainController.

Comment: No i'm not using ARC (it's off).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what the problem was (but not why...); I was using

```
[controller initGUI:self.view];
```

changing that to:

```
[controller initGUI:self.window.rootViewController.view];
```

makes it work. I don't know why.

For people who are interesting to do this same thing (like I said; I couldn't find even one example on the web), here is the simplified project; https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6134596/TestDelegate.zip

Comment: What was self.view? Where did that come from?

Comment: Your project at dropbox just crashes when I run it.

Comment: @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *view; it's hooked up in the builder. I assumed it was the root view but that might have been wrong?

Comment: Crashes? :) Oh that's weird; it works well here... I tried in iOS 5+6. Screeny; https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6134596/Screen%20Shot%202013-04-26%20at%203.10.54%20AM.png

Comment: It gives me "A view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a time!" You're taking the view of your root view controller and assigning that to your TestUIDelegate. That's not a good thing to do. I don't know how it can be working for you.

Comment: So is there a good way to have two different delegate classes attached to one view programmatically?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28926/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-charless)

Comment: I changed the UIViewController in the code to NSObject; now it seems legal. I updated the example in dropbox.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add textFieldShouldReturn to get the keyboard to dismiss:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

TextFieldDidEndEditing will then be called as well, but you need to resignFirstResponder before that happens.

Comment: The problem is that none of the delegates are called. Not this one or any of the others. That's the issue and I have no clue why that is.

Comment: I have; it's there; same behaviour unfortunately :(

Comment: @CharlesS, well, I copied your code, and it worked fine for me. You should post the code in the app delegate (I assume that's what you mean by MainController).

Comment: No, that's the whole point; I *do not* want to have the MainController be the delegate; I want my TestUIDelegate to be the delegate. If I use the MainController it works, but that's completely useless to what I want to achieve unfortunately.

Comment: @CharlesS, I don't mean the delegate of the text field, I mean the application delegate -- the one that the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method is in. I want you to post the code in there, not change your code.

Comment: To reproduce, just make a very basic HelloWorld project with 1 .h and one .m file; then add @interface TestUIDelegate : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> to the .h file, add the implementation of TestUIDelegate to the .m file and then instantiate the controller from the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method of your main project class. You'll see the textfield appear but it won't call the delegate methods. I'll make such a simple project now and post it here.